Вид или тип - в описании к достижению в игре
Перевожу достижения в игре на русский язык и замешкался на переводе подобных описаний:

Добудьте каждый вид руды

Создайте каждый тип плиты


Мне кажется такое неправильным, и я не очень понимаю, где использовать "вид", а где "тип"? Предположим что плиты это декорации и отличаются лишь материалом, из которого они сделаны, но форма у плиты всегда одна и та же. У руд же, наоборот, более стратегический смысл и у каждого минерала свои особенности и предназначение в игре.
Стоит ли в моей ситуации проводить аналогии между игрой и реальным миром, или можно использовать всегда одно слово, например "тип"?

Словарь Ушакова:

ВИД2, вида, муж. (научн.).

Подчиненное понятие, входящее в состав другого, высшего понятия - рода (филос.). Понятие дерево по отношению к родовому понятию растение
является видом.
Совокупность особей, обладающих одинаковыми признаками, единица классификации животных и растений, подчиненная роду, как высшей
единице (биол.). Ветла - вид ивы.


То есть вид употребимо для классификации живых существ имеющих род, а для РУДЫ лучше использовать ТИП. В тоже время для создаваемых ПЛИТ(различной формы?) лучше использовать ВИД, имея ввиду "внешний вид", то есть различную форму, но не ВИД ПЛИТ, а "создайте плиту каждого вида" или даже лучше "произведите/постройте/разместите плиту каждого вида".

ВИД1, вида, муж.

только ед. Внешность, наружность. Дом имеет опрятный вид. Местность имела унылый вид. || Внешние очертания, формы. Шарообразный вид. ||
перен. Внешнее подобие. Придать упреку вид шутки. || Внешний облик как
выражение внутреннего состояния, характера. Принять серьезный вид.
Независимый вид. Больной вид.


То есть у плиты есть (внешний)вид, а у руды, золотой руды, например, нет вида, она может быть любой формы. Так что, если о форме плит, то можно "вид", а если о том из чего плиты, то лучше "тип".

Получается, что вид нужно использовать когда у собираемых вещей меняется форма (например, одна плита квадратная, а другая - круглая). Но если у всех плит не меняется форма, а меняется лишь текстура (и материал, из которого она изготовлена), то лучше будет тип

Но, вот, по поводу принадлежности к роду, немного не понял. Получается, если достижение будет требовать собрать каждый цветок, то тут 100% вид используем? Потому что цветы это результат генерации мира, что сравнимо с естественной средой. И, выходит, что даже если у цветков одна и та же форма, тип использовать нельзя, так как условная ромашка это вид цветка в реальном мире?

Для цветов лучше вид, для форм лучше вид, а для разных руд лучше тип. Цветы единообразны, потому что относятся к одному виду, они типа живые. Вид связан с процессом создания, цветок будет одним и тем же, независимо, где он вырос, хотя может быть разным - цветущим, засохшим, в зависимости от того, когда собрали, то есть зависит от действий человека. А руда наоборот, время на неё никак не влияет, поэтому не зависит в целом от того, когда человек её добудет. В игре конечно все выдуманное. Но по идее различия должны быть такие. Цветы - возобновляемый ресурс, руда нет.
